# Where to specify "MaxRetry" and "Timeout" variables in the Elasticsearch / Nest Bulk API?

Tags: nest, elasticsearch

Question: Where to specify bulk operation "MaxRetry" or "Timeout" variables used in the NEST bulk API?

When I do the following bulk operation, the program stops after successfully inserting 60K records. I got a MaxRetryException in Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandlerBase.cs.
So, I am thinking to increase the MaxRetry number or Timeout seconds to overcome this problem, Am I on the right path?

```
var counter = 0;
var indexName = "SomeIndexName";
var indexType = "SomeType";
var routingString = "SomeRouting";
var bulkDescriptor = new BulkDescriptor();

while (await result.ReadAsync())
{
      counter++;
      var document = GetDocumentObject<T>(result);
      var idString = GetID(result);

      bulkDescriptor.Index<T>(op => op
          .Routing(routingString)
          .Index(indexName)
          .Type(indexType)
          .Id(idString)
          .Document(document));
      if (counter % 1000 == 0)
      {
         var bulkResponse = await client.BulkAsync(bulkDescriptor);
         bulkDescriptor = new BulkDescriptor();
      }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I tested and that is how I specify the timeout & max retries:

```
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(_connectionPool)
    .SetTimeout(1000*30)  // 30 minutes timeout
    .MaximumRetries(5);   // 5 times retry
var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
```